# How to get image from a folder path in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I'm trying to understand how to make a get a file from my project
I'm using visual studio 2010, and I have a folder in my wpf project that is called: Images

How can I get an image from that folder, I'am trying:

```
return @"/Images/"+ name+".jpg";
```

the folder it self is in :  `C:\Users\Boaz-Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FinalSadna\FinalSadna\Images`

But it doesnt work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: And where, relative to the running assembly is that folder at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can look at something like this

```
string imageName = name + ".jpg";
var path = Path.Combine(GetApplicationFolder(), "/Images/" + imageName);
```

if you want to find it via the Assembly you could use the following as well

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
var uriSource = new Uri(@"/FinalSadna;component/imagename.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the relative path, at least from the code we can see, is relative to the output exe file. I doubt this folder is bin>debug or bin>release. So you would need to go back a certain number of directories (hopes). [This](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html) article explains relative paths very well.

**EDIT:**

Unless you have custom compiling option enabled, then you are incorrectly referencing the relative path. Have a look the above link, please.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: from what you are saying i need to use this:
@"../../Images/"+ name+".jpg";
and this is not working for me aswell

Comment: @DaerikFisher I believe that is correct. Sounds like it helped you!