# Deployment of application with sound effects and txt document included

Tags: windows, deployment

I have made an simple application which uses few sound effects and .txt document for storing some info(those files are stored into my projects bin/Debug directory).The app works fine on my PC, but when I run the .exe file on other computer, it works until the sound or .txt file is necessary(then is gives me a warning message telling that sound or .txt file isn't reachable).
How can I solve this problem, i mean, what should I do to make my app work properly on other PC's as well.Thanks!

Edit:
Here it the code which uses only sound effects(i'm changing them, so there are more than one sound)

```
{
public partial class GameScreen : Form
    {
        bool sound;
        string sound1;
        string sound2;
        string sound3;
        SoundPlayer sp1;
        public GameScreen(string PlayerName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sound1 = "Air_Horn.wav";
            sound2 = "TaDam.wav";
            sound3 = "Bonus.wav";
            sp1 = new SoundPlayer(sound1);
            sound = true;
        }

        private void GameScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sound == true)sp1.Play();
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the code using sound effects and .txt document:

```
{
    public partial class VictoryForm : Form
    {
        SoundPlayer sp2;
        string results;
        bool sound_eff;
        public VictoryForm(string statistics, bool _sound)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sp2 = new SoundPlayer("Cheering3.wav");
            results = statistics;
            sound_eff = _sound;
        }

        private void VictoryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sound_eff == true) sp2.Play();
        }

        private void VictoryForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Results.txt", true);
            sw.WriteLine(results);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is accessing either file, without that people may simply be guessing. A code sample should reveal the issue pretty quickly.

Comment: For sure. I have added the code that uses sounds and .txt document.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you a) have not copied your texts or sound to the other computer or b) use wrong path to them. To be sure, print out the full path to the text or sound files and check if the intended files are really there. I bet they are not. ...

Btw, the contructor of StreamWriter says about its arguments: path = "The complete file path to write to", but your "Result.txt" is not a full path.

Comment: What I meant was creating app, which caries those files with it...Like sort of archive which contains either exe, wav and txt files...And when you extract that archive on other PC's, the .exe automatically knows where to find the text file and sound effects

Comment: In that case you need to 1) Use proper relative paths in your code. I mean relative to your application path. This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308846/relative-path-c-sharp and 2) Pack your application to zip or to an windows installer file (msi) and unpack it on the destination machine with the correct folder structure.